# Question relating to Direct sum of two copies of polynomial Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, modules

I know the direct sum of two k-algebra over the same field is again a k-algebra where K is a field.

I want to know if this algebra $K[X] \oplus K[X]$ is isomorphic to any other algebra?
 and in general what do we know about it? 
any link or book reference will appreciate it too.